# Table visibility using Javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button, html

I have 4 radiobuttons and 4 tables  in a webpage. When I check one radiobutton the corresponding table should be made visible and the others invisible. The same logic is applicable to all 4 radiobuttons. Please tell me the Javascript required for this.

I tried the following Javascript, but its not working.

```
function showTable1(){
        if(opt1.checked)
        {
            tbl1.style.visibility="visible";
            tbl2.style.visibility="hidden";
        tbl3.style.visibility="hidden";
        tbl4.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
        }
```

This is how I call this method:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="opt1" runat="server" Text="1"  OnCheckedChanged="javascript:showTable1()" Checked="True"   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you not already aware that using `"visibility"` has no affect on surrounding content. where `"display"` will remove the element from rendering flow causing the surrpunding content to fill the space which was occupied by the former element.

See if this helps add "this" to `onclick="javascript:showTable(this)`

```
function showTable(tblNum){

var num_tables = 4; // expeted number of table to hide / show


document.getElementById(tblNum.id).checked = "checked"; // set reffering element as checked

for (var i = 1; i < num_tables + 1; i++) { 

if (document.getElementById((tblNum.id).slice(0, -1) + i).checked){

   //alert("Show table: " + (tblNum.id).slice(-1));


   document.getElementById("tbl" + (tblNum.id).slice(-1)).style.visibility = "visible";

}else{
//alert("Hide table: " + i);

document.getElementById(("tbl" + i)).style.visibility="hidden"
}

}
}
```

you will need to set the style attribute values for `visibility` or `display` on to the table elements as well.

Answer (score 1):

USE OnClientClick method to define your javascript :-

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="opt1" runat="server" Text="1"  OnClientClick="showTable1()" Checked="True"   />



  function showTable1(){
                    if (window.document.getElementById("opt1").checked == true ){
                      document.getElementById("tbl1").style.display=none;//for hide and use block to show

                    }
                    else if (window.document.getElementById("RadioBtNo").checked == true ){
                       //do something here
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i tried giving it in the onclientclick event.. but the script is not getting fired. i put a alert in the script and tested. but the alert was not fired

Comment: try using HTML controls instead of asp controls:   <input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" runat="server"/>Yes
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="0" runat="server"/>No

Comment: same problem. the function is not been called. :(

Comment: some small mistake like spelling mistake or anything you are doing..otherwise it should work. check your code once carefully..:)

Comment: ya actually if you are using HTML control then you can define your javascript in onclick event but if you are using asp control then onclick event postback to server. you cannot define javascript in onclick event for asp control.so for that purpose we use onclientclick event, hope it may be helpful to  you to understand the working of control and evnts..)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function showTable1(){
    if(document.getElementById("opt1").checked)
    {
        tbl1.style.display="";
        tbl2.style.display="none";
        tbl3.style.display="none";
        tbl4.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the id "tbl1" to the table as  and in your code select the element as

```
var tbl1 = document.getElementById('tbl1');
```

This function after assigning the Ids to the table will look like

```
function showTable1(){
    var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1'); // select option by using Id
    var tbl1 = document.getElementById('tbl1');
    var tbl2 = document.getElementById('tbl2');
    var tbl3 = document.getElementById('tbl3');
    var tbl4 = document.getElementById('tbl4');

    if(opt1.checked)
    {
        tbl1.style.display="block";
        tbl2.style.display="none";
    tbl3.style.display="none";
    tbl4.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried this method. but my error is coming at the calling point. syntax error

Comment: Did you add "opt1" as the id of radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I think document.getelementbyid('opt1') does not work for asp.net control. We might need to use something like document.getelementbyid('<%# opt1.ClientID %>') something like this.
Because in asp.net control the ids get changed.

PLease tell if you have any problem.

You can preferably use jquery with the selectors also. THey provide very good support

Comment: my issue is that the javascript is not been fired for the onclientclick event and for oncheckchanged iam getting a syntax error

Comment: @Navya you can please run the webpage in IE and then you can find the syntax error at which line it is breaking by clicking at the left bottom link. There might be some brace missing. You can also try firebug.